# How to use iter(v,w) with a function?

Tags: python, iterator

I was study iter(), in its official document, it says i can do iter(v,w) , so that iter() will call v until it return the value w, then it stops.

But I tried for half hour, and still can't work out a function that can return multiple result.

Here is my code, I expect it to return 1,2,3,4,5:

```
def x():
    for i in range(10):
        return i

a = iter(x, 5)
a.next()
```

I know that when I return i, that I was actually quit the function.

Maybe it's impossible to return result for multiple times for a function.

But how should I use a function to make that iter(x,5) work properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iter()` calls the function **each time**. Your function returns the same value on each call (the first number in the `range(10)` list).

You could change the function to use a global to illustrate how `iter()` with two arguments works:

```
i = 0
def f():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i

for x in iter(f, 5):
    print x
```

Now each time `f()` is called, a new number is returned. You could use a default argument, or an instance with state and a method on that instance, too. As long as the function returns something different *when called more than once* it'll fit the `iter(a, b)` usecase.

`iter()` with two arguments is most often called with a method, where the state of an instance changes with each call. The `.readline()` method on a file object, for example:

```
for line in iter(fileobject.readline, ''):
```

which would work exactly like iterating over the `fileobject` iterable directly, except it wouldn't use the internal file iteration buffer. That could sometimes be a requirement (see the [`file.next()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) for more information on the file iteration buffer).

You can of course pass in a `lambda` function too:

```
for chunk in iter(lambda: fileobject.read(2048), ''):
```

Now we are reading the file object is chunks of up to 2048 bytes instead of line by line.

Comment: I had no idea the two-argument form of `iter()` worked like this. (+1)

Comment: I wonder if it would be instructive to also show an example with a callable *object* instead of a function, perhaps suggesting that it might be a good way to avoid global state.

Comment: @NPE: I tried to provide the shortest and simplest example possible. The general usecase is to use this with instances though, as expanded upon in the second half. I think I'll let this stand.

Comment: Fair enough. :) On an unrelated note, I am not sure what you mean by *it wouldn't use the internal file iteration buffer*. It could be just me though...

Comment: @NPE: see the [`file.next()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next).

Comment: Advocating `global` over a cleaner generator, tsk tsk :)

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: a generator would not illustrate the `iter(x, y)` usecase.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, think I got it, my function only produce 1 result, and I called iter() only once. I'll write an answer to prove my understanding.

Comment: @Zen: Your function *always* returns `0`, it'll never return `5`. And yes, `iterator.next()` is called only once in your example, but you could keep calling it over and over again and it'll always return `0` and never raise `StopIteration`.

Comment: @Zen: I'd write an answer only if you feel you need to explain to future visitors about something new, over and above what I put in my answer, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but how should I explain to you in comment with code that I understood what you say? Because I may misunderstood it when I thought I understood it.

Comment: @Zen: You don't need to prove to me that you understood what I said, though. :-) You clearly did; I understood that from your comment already!

Answer (score 1):

After @Martjin Pieters's answer, I've got the idea.

And this is the piece of code I wrote which can use iter(v,w) correctly:

```
import random

def x():
    return random.randrange(1,10)

a = iter(x,5)

while True:
    print a.next()
```

In this code, a.next() will return the value a get from x(), until x() returns 5, then it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a generator function, via the `yield` keyword.  Example:

```
def x():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```